# Csv-commons withIgnoreEmptyLines method doesn't have affect

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I wrote following code:

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withIgnoreEmptyLines().withSkipHeaderRecord().parse(in);
records.forEach(record -> {...
```

foreach lambda invokes for empty lines too.

I have empty lines because of excel.

empty lines looks like this:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Why does it work so?

How to make it working as expected?

### P.S.

withSkipHeaderRecord doesn't work too

Comment: ignoreEmptyLines() only ignores completely empty lines, i.e. no character at all, not a list of commas as you have here, which is not an empty line, but rather a line with all values as empty.

Comment: @centic, is where out of the box way to ignore lines, as I described?

Comment: @centic, what about skip header line ?

Comment: No, I don't see built-in functionality for that, you will need to check and skip the records on your end.

Comment: @centic, What about method **withSkipHeaderRecord** https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withSkipHeaderRecord-boolean- ?

Comment: I don't think it talks about skipping empy/null lines, or?

Comment: @centic, yes, but it doesn't skip header either